# Possible eigenvalue of Laplacian

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I came across an exercise of book Spectra of Graphs.

> Show that there does not exist graph whose adjacency matrix eigenvalue
>   is -1/2.

Any thougts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that graph eigenvalues are algebraic integers. Prove that algebraic integers that are rational must be integers.